# Table not visible but accessible in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio, and I encounter something that I haven't seen before and I probably just need some explanation no technical coding involved.

So I was working on some query and need to find tables and usually I check Object Explorer and directly right click table for the first 1000 records. I was joining my claims table with another table for amounts paid column, and I couldn't locate my second table.

I could use `select *` to get the columns of the table, but it is not visible in my object explorer. Not sure if I am blocked from viewing, but this is my first time seeing it.

I am showing you where my claims table ends and right after it is the Communication table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `cClaimParticipants` is a **view**.

Comment: And if you don't see it under views, maybe it was just created and you need to right click on the views folder in object explorer and click refresh

Comment: Yes, under the views folder (instead of tables). [Read about views here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That you, at least, need to be looking under Views, not Tables.

Comment: Thank you guys for explaining.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + R friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for an official answer (answers were given in OP comments):

The "table" you can't find is actually a `View` and can be found in the Views subfolder under the Database.

[image]